# Pandas - Getting a Key Error when the Key Exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to join two dataframes in Pandas.

The first frame is called Trades and has these columns:

```
TRADE DATE
ACCOUNT
COMPANY
COST CENTER
CURRENCY
```

The second frame is called Company_Mapping and has these columns:

```
ACTUAL_COMPANY_ID
MAPPED_COMPANY_ID
```

I'm trying to join them with this code:

```
trade_df = pd.merge(left=Trades, right = Company_Mapping, how = 'left', left_on = 'COMPANY', right_on = 'ACTUAL_COMPANY_ID'
```

This returns:

```
KeyError: 'COMPANY'
```

I've double checked the spelling and COMPANY is clearly in Trades, and I have no clue what would cause this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `print Trades.columns` and report back what is printed out.

Comment: @piRSquared TRADE DATE,ACCOUNT,COMPANY,COST CENTER,CURRENCY

Comment: Are there extraneous characters in any of the column names? Like `TRADE DATE `?

Comment: That's not how its presented.  It looks like `Index(['co'], dtype='object')`.  Please copy and paste the output form that print statement

Comment: @piRSquared Sorry, just took the column names before. Here's the full: Index([u'TRADE DATE,ACCOUNT,COMPANY,COST CENTER,CURRENCY'], dtype = 'object')

Comment: Thank you and there in lies your problem.  You have a single column with a big mashed up string.  Look at `df.shape`.  It should be some tuple with a `1` as the second element `(x, 1)`.  If you want to solve this problem, you'll want to show us a sample of the file you are parsing, or a sample of the dataframe so we can fix it.  Then your merge should work.  Also, your other dataframe may suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Aha! That was the problem. I read both frames from csv files, and I didn't notice that the file producer had started using a different separator. That screwed up the import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Trades` dataframe has a single column with all the intended column names mashed together into a single string.  Check the code that parses your file.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you read your file with the right seperation.

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=';')
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=',')
```

Answer (score -1):

Essentially keyError is shown in pandas python when there is no such column name for example you are typing `df.loc[df['one']==10]` but column name 'one does not exist' whoever if it exist and you are still getting the same error try place try and except statement my problem was solved using try and except statement.

for example

```
try:
   df_new = df.loc[df['one']==10]
except KeyError:
   print('No KeyError')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone have the same problem, sometimes you need to `transpose` your dataframe:

```py
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
    # A  B  C
    # -------
    # 1  2  3
    # 4  5  6

    new_df = pd.DataFrame([df['A'], df['B']])
    # A | 1 4
    # B | 2 5
    
    new_df['A'] # KeyError
    
    new_df = new_df.T
    # A B
    # --- 
    # 1 2
    # 4 5

    new_df['A'] # KeyError
    # A
    # - 
    # 1
    # 4
```